# Unable to animate button after using :after property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my head around pseudo elements, but cannot seem to get a simple button animation to work with it.

On hover, I want a panel to go from bottom to top. Similar to the button found on [this page](https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/) (1st row, 2nd button).

From my understanding, using `.btn:after` will add any css *after* each `.btn` class. But then why doesn't this work?

```css
.btn {
    border: 1px solid #65bb39;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #65bb39;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid #65bb39;
    background-color: #fff;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="btn">Test</span>
</div>
```

On hover, I want the border to turn `#65bb39` and the block to fill white (from bottom to top).

Of course, any feedback on `before` and `after` is appreciated!

Comment: and where is the hover state defined?

Comment: Your understanding is also incorrect. `:after` does not change the CSS of the button

Comment: If you inspect the element (button) on that page you like you will find everything you want rather than spend some time typing your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So will need to add a hover state to the btn:after and then transition css between the two states. See snippet below.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.btn {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover{
    color: #65bb39;
}

.btn:after, .btn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    color: #65bb39;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid #65bb39;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:before {
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #65bb39;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn:after {
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn:hover:after {    
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm starting to understand psuedo elements better after seeing your code. I've tried to use your code (amended the button style slightly) but I'm not getting the hover on the BG. Anything I'm doing wrong? - https://jsfiddle.net/4ara6uL7/

Comment: ah nevermind, it was a z-index issue! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.button {
  height: 75px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #65bb39;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
  .button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #65bb39;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }

.button:hover {
  color: #65bb39;
}
  .button:hover::after {
    height: 0%;
  }
    .button:hover::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
      z-index: -2;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```css
.btn {
  border: 3px solid #65bb39;
  background: none;
  color: #65bb39;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #65bb39;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="btn">Test</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
.btn {
  border: 2px solid #65bb39;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #65bb39;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #65bb39;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn:hover:after {
  height: 0%;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span class="btn">Test</span></div>
```